# POST API giving error that database not initialized for given JNDI Properties ? How to solve this issue?

Tags: oracle, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I am trying to make a small POST API, for which I want to use DBlookup using carbon Datasource. I have connected deployment.toml to Oracle 11.2 "XE" database by adding details in `deployment.toml`. However, when I run the server, I get this warning.

```
WARN {DBLookupMediator} - DataSource: XE was not initialized for given JNDI properties :{}
```

Why is this problem happening? Any leads would mean a lot.
Thanks

I tried to write all code properly, using wso2 documentation. However, I am unable to connect it to oracle db as mentioned above errror comes as follows: * WARN {DBLookupMediator} - DataSource: XE was not initialized for given JNDI properties :{} *
Below is the the configuration I added in deployment.toml:

```
[[datasource]]
id = "XE"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE"
username = "tcods"
password = "123"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
```

Comment: Add your configurations and the integration source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `jdbc/` prefix in your connection pool configurations for the `dsName`.

```xml
<connection>
   <pool>
     <dsName>jdbc/XE</dsName>
   </pool>
</connection>
```